# Calculate element height and apply to other element

Tags: jquery, padding, sticky-footer

Using a 'sticky footer', I need to have the bottom padding on the content div equal to the footer height.

I would like to use jQuery to grab the footer height and apply that value to the content div bottom padding value.

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from writing that code?

Comment: Not very constructive is that comment? I had tried and failed...

Comment: Then provide the code and we can point out where you went wrong. StackOverflow is a place for help, not a place for you to find someone to write code for free when you can't be bothered trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var height = $('#footer').height();
$('#content').css('padding-bottom',height+'px');
```

I think this is the solution to your problem

Comment: Fantastic! I was actually not far off... was just a case of stringing it together - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var height = $('#footer').height();

$('.other').css('paddingBottom', height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste some code? :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
    $('#contentarea').css('padding-bottom',footerheight+'px');

});
</script>
```